# JAX-RS REST API Variable Sharing Between Requests

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, api-design

I'm trying to determine the best design for my REST API. I have a number of steps that happen sequentially (data manipulation pipeline) that each have individual REST calls.

I have been saving the intermediate data generated into files on the server to keep the REST API stateless. However, I'm worried about the costs associated with File I/O and serialization since I write out to 3-4 files and then read them again, later on in the pipeline.

An alternative is to save them in memory during the run of the Java web app, but that seems to make the system stateful. What are pros/cons of these options?

Comment: Just because you save the state to a file rather than keeping it in memory doesn't make your service stateless, perhaps even less so as the state becomes _persistent_ state rather than volatile state. Consider this: what happens if the client chooses to abort in the middle of the pipeline (say after REST call 2/4)? Then you have _persistent_ state left at the server. If you want to keep your server truly stateless, you'd need to return the state to the client for each call such that the client could supply that state to the server in the subsequent call (as pointed out by @Steve11235).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saving intermediate results anywhere makes your services stateful. How you store state has a big impact on scalability. Once your services are running on multiple instances, the state information has to be shared among them. If you use files, then you must use a file server accessible to all of them. Another option is a database.

You could also consider passing the intermediate data to the client; the client would pass the data back on the next call.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The issue that I have with this is that these intermediate files can get quite large. It would take both time and resources to send them back and forth between the client. Is there no design pattern that allows intermediate results and statelessness?

Comment: Didn't mean to ignore your question. No, the two things are exclusive. For large intermediate files, I would look to network storage for the files, rather than a database. You might want to save metadata in a database.